# How to convert default instance to named instance in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

How to convert default instance to named instance in SQL Server 2012?

By mistake I have chosen default instance option and installed. Now I have to change to named instance. How to change?

Answer (score 10):

Install the named instance, move the databases, agent jobs, etc over to it, then uninstall the now unused default instance.

Comment: Good point migrating anything you've created.  I assumed, bad habit, that he noticed the problem immediately after installation.

Comment: Instead of moving jobs ( if there are many)- just restore msdb using backup restore.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is you can't.  If you aren't going to use the default instance, just uninstall it.  You can install SQL Server again and create a named instance.

Answer (score 1):

you can rename your instance but you can not change the named instance to default instance and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

How to convert named instance to default instance in SQL Server 2012?

---

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Click SQL Server Network Configuration
3. Click Protocols for INSTANCENAME you want to make available
4. Right-click TCP/IP and click Enabled
5. Right-click TCP/IP and go to Properties
6. Go to the IP Addresses tab
7. Scroll down to the IPAll section
8. Clear the field TCP Dynamic Ports (i.e. empty/blank)
9. Set TCP Port to 1433
10. Click Ok
11. Go to SQL Server Services
12. Right-click your SQL Server (INSTANCENAME) and click Restart

Comment: The opposite question may be useful as well but it deserves to be asked and answered separately. You can post a question together with the answer by ticking the "Answer your own question" checkbox at the bottom of the [Ask a question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page. Read more at [Can I answer my own question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) Also, please consider registering your account so that you don't accidentally lose ownership of your posts.

Comment: There are numerous reasons why simply changing the port of a named instance to 1433 is not the equivalent of making it the default instance.  Yes, you won't need to specify the name of the instance when connecting to the server, however anything that checks the name of the server, such as `@@SERVERNAME`, will still see the instance name.

Comment: It's true this doesn't answer the question asked, and would be better as a seperate question and answer, but it _was_ exactly what I wanted to do. And, no, I don't care that it will not actually be the "default" instance.